# Error in Query String in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code and am getting an error:

> Input string was not in a correct format

```
string query = "INSERT INTO tbl_Course_Master(ShortForm,CourseName,DeptID,CourseDuration)VALUES(@sf,@cn,@did,@cd)";
conn.Open();
try
{
    command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    command.Parameters.Add("@sf", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    command.Parameters.Add("@cn", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    command.Parameters.Add("@did", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters.Add("@cd", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@sf"].Value = txt_Short_Form.Text.ToString();
    command.Parameters["@cn"].Value = txt_Course_Name.Text.ToString();
    command.Parameters["@did"].Value = Int16.Parse(lbl_Dept_ID.Text);
    command.Parameters["@cd"].Value = Int16.Parse(txt_Duration.Text);
    int row = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (row > 0)
    {
        lbl_Message.Text = "Data Is Inserted Sucessfully.....";
        clearData();
    }
    else lbl_Message.Text = "Error In Data Insertion.........";
    lbl_Message.Visible = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lbl_Message.Text = "Error:" + ex.Message.ToString();
    lbl_Message.Visible = true;
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. First of all, [good formatting is your friend](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Use it. Second, tell the specific line that throws this exception. What are the `lbl_Dept_ID.Text` and `txt_Duration.Text` values and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Using my psychic debugging skills, one of `lbl_Dept_ID.Text` or `txt_Duration.Text` is not a valid integer.

Comment: It looks quite likely that this is happening when you try to parse your Int16 parameters - do you have validation on these inputs to ensure they are a number in the appropriate range?

Comment: thank you so much to all of you my problem is solved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is one of the values you are using in the Int.Parse or .ToString() methods NULL or empty? This error can occur when attempting to parse/convert a blank/null value to a certain data type.